# How to reference a class variable outside of the class in a module file in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am trying to reference a class variable in a class in a module file:

```
require 'pry'
require_relative '../lib/concerns/memorable'

class Song
  extend Memorable::ClassMethods
  extend Findable::ClassMethods
  attr_accessor :name
  attr_reader :artist

  @@songs = []

  def initialize
    @@songs << self
  end

  # def self.find_by_name(name)
  #   @@songs.detect{|a| a.name == name}
  # end

  def self.all
    @@songs
  end

  # def self.reset_all
  #   self.all.clear
  # end
  #
  # def self.count
  #   self.all.count
  # end

  def artist=(artist)
    @artist = artist
  end

  def to_param
    name.downcase.gsub(' ', '-')
  end
end
```

```
module Findable
  module ClassMethods

    def all
      @@artists
    end

    def all
      @@songs
    end

    def find_by_name(name)
      @@songs.detect{|a| a.name == name}
    end

    def self.find_by_name(name)
      @@artists.detect{|a| a.name == name}
    end

 end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [class_variable_get](https://apidock.com/ruby/Module/class_variable_get):

```rb
    module Findable
      module ClassMethods

        def all
          self.class_variable_get(:@@songs)
        end

        def find_by_name(name)
          self.class_variable_get(:@@songs).detect{|a| a.name == name}
        end

      end
    end
```

Comment: Without a variable `class_variable_get` in scope the method will be called on `self` by default. So you could leave out `self` in `self.class_variable_get(:@@songs)`. `self....` is mostly used to explicitly reference the method when you have a variable with the same name in scope. For example `name = self.name`. Or when using reserved keywords. For example `self.class` (`class` on it's own opens a new class).

Comment: I did give this a shot but it didn't clear out the NameError

Comment: For the example above you would have to have @@songs defined in the class that extends Findable (Song in this case). Using your code, I have gotten this to work for songs. If you want it to be more generically useful, you could define @@findable_items in each class that inherits from Findable. Then you would have to use class_variable_get(:@@findable_items) and you could use it in other classes (such as Artists) as long as you have a @@findable_items class variable defined.

Answer (score 0):

A common way to implement shared behaviour is to require a certain interface. For example the core [`Enumerable`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Enumerable.html) module requires you to implement `each` for most of the methods to work. (Some methods like `sort` needs the elements within to implement the `<=>` operator.)

Applying this to what you're trying to do you could require the classes that extend the module to implement an `all` method. You don't need to check this specifically. Just assume the `all` method is there, if it's not the user will see an exception *"NoMethodError: undefined method 'all' for Song:Class"* which is pretty clear.

```rb
module Findable
  ##
  # The class extending Findable::ClassMethods must provide a method
  # `all` which returns an Enumerable collection.
  module ClassMethods
    def find_by_name(name)
      all.select { |instance| instance.name == name }
    end
  end
end

class Song
  extend Findable::ClassMethods
  attr_accessor :name, :artist

  @@songs = []

  def initialize
    @@songs << self
  end

  def self.all
    @@songs
  end
end

foo = Song.new
foo.name = "foo"

bar = Song.new
bar.name = "bar"

Song.all
#=> [#<Song:0x0055828c8ca3e8 @name="foo">, #<Song:0x0055828c8cc9e0 @name="bar">]

Song.find_by_name("foo")
#=> [#<Song:0x0055828c8ca3e8 @name="foo">]
```

Comment: I tried refactoring it a bit with this and it didn't work out too well

Comment: @laurenceC This does resolve the scenario as given in the question, although not by accessing the class variable from the module. What is the problem you're facing?

Comment: Turns out I was not supposed to reference directly, but I got it working. Thanks